# Bootstrap footer - How to align it to the right and give spacing

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is my code:

```
<footer>
        <p>© Company 2014</p><a href="#">Pricing</a><a href="#">Contact</a><a href="#">Terms</a>
</footer>
```

I'm trying to not only align the links to the right but also give each one a spacing so they are not directly next to each other.

I know I can float it right and give it isn't own CSS but im trying to avoid using custom CSS, is there any css classes or html markup I can add from bootstrap to get this effect without having to add custom rules?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

See [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/fUltcZAv78) for a working example.

```
    <footer>
      <p class="pull-left">© Company 2014</p>
      <div class="pull-right">
          <ul class="list-inline">
             <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Terms</a></li>
          </ul>
      </div>
    </footer>
```

The `list-inline` utility places everything in a single line using `inline-block` with extra padding. It is a Bootstrap utility.

Answer (score 4):

class pull-right will float them right

```
<footer class="pull-right">
```

Comment: And the spacing between the items, should I make them a list, would that give me the spacing?

Comment: Also I only want the links on the right not the whole footer

Comment: if you want just links then give each of them a class pull-right <a href="#" class="pull-right"> if you want spacing I think the best way is to make you css with some margin

Comment: don't do that with inline classes...see my answer using CSS.  I just updated my answer to move only links to the right.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

CSS

```
footer a{
     float: right;
     margin-right: 30px;
     //you can adjust this margin to change spacing.  
     //you can also play around with using margin instead of margin-right
}
```

HTML

```
<footer>
     <p>© Company 2014</p>
     <a href="#">Pricing</a>
     <a href="#">Contact</a>
     <a href="#">Terms</a>
</footer>
```

[Bootply Demo](http://www.bootply.com/Aa7WHlNgw2)

If you want the links to be on the same line as your `<p>` tag then just put the `<a>` tags within the `<p>` tag as [shown here](http://www.bootply.com/pEWaPXFGBU).

Answer (score 2):

The Class  `.pull-right` will align the div into right corner

Try this

```
<footer class="pull-right">
        © Company 2014 | <a href="#">Pricing</a> | <a href="#">Contact</a> | <a href="#">Terms</a>
</footer>
```

This will solve your iniline display as well.

Good Day

Answer (score 1):

With Bootstrap v5.0:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/float/

```
<div class="float-start"> </div>
<div class="float-end"> </div>
<div class="float-none"> </div>
```