# How to align the content of a footer in small devices

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I basically have a footer with all my social media links on the right and a paragraph one the left as the my HTML code and CSS show:

```css
.socialmedia{
  color:#ffffcc;
  padding: 25px;
  background: #262626;
}
.socialmedia a{
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  padding-left: 20px;   
}
.socialmedia a{
  border-radius: 60%;
}
```

```html
<footer class="socialmedia">
  <div class="container"> 
    &copy; Acacia House 2015
    <span><a class="mediapics" href="https://www.facebook.com"><img class="img-responsive" src="facebook.png" alt="Attempt" width="30" style="border-radius:50px"></a></span>
    <span><a class="mediapics" href="https://www.google.com"><img class="img-responsive" src="google.png" alt="Attempt" width="30" style="border-radius:50px"></a></span>
    <span><a class="mediapics" href="https://www.twitter.com"><img class="img-responsive" src="facebook.png" alt="Attempt" width="30" style="border-radius:50px"></a></span>               
  </div>

</footer>
```

Problem is that one of the social media images moves up when I fully scale the page down and that three image do not properly align with the paragraph as they go one after each other(paragraph first and the images aligned under).

How can I adjust the responsiveness there?

Comment: Try making them all float left. That should make them appear under each other when the screen is small.

Comment: if you are using bootstrap you can use `pull-right` and `pull-left` class. Please refer this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24935384/2845151)